# Can I know if a user removes notification from notification center?

Tags: ios

As the title states, can I possibly know if an iOS user removes or clear notifications for my app in the notification center? I only want to know for tracking purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty confident that this is not possible. One solution would be to track the number of notifications that the user clicks/opens and compare it to the number of notifications sent to the user (remember that Apple don't guarantees the arrival of a push). I know that this is not the same as tracking the number of notifications that the user cancels/closes, but unfortunately it's not possible the other way around.

Something similar has been discussed here:
[How can I handle unread push notifications in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12278299/how-can-i-handle-unread-push-notifications-in-ios)

Comment: Thanks @steffan-d-sommer! I guessed that would be the case.